# why doesn't layoutInflater work in class level in android from kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I discover something strange in android studio while write a code. that is layoutInflater doesn't work in class out of method. if i write a the following code and run it, app doesn't work.
why does this phenomenon happen?

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val li = layoutInflater
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val li = layoutInflater
```

This is equivalent to:

```kotlin
val li = getLayoutInflater()
```

In general, do not call methods on `Activity` or superclasses — such as `getLayoutInflater()` — until after you call `super.onCreate()`. Usually, those methods will not work, because the activity has not been initialized yet.

Comment: so to call getLayoutInflater method in other class how do i have to do?

Comment: @himaru: I do not know what you mean by "in other class". You can pass the `Activity` or a `LayoutInflater` to the other class -- you just have to be careful in when you do that. In [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/vFINAL/RecyclerViewBasics) from [this free book](http://commonsware.com/Jetpack), I pass a `LayoutInflater` to a subclass of `RecyclerView.Adapter`, for example.

Comment: can I ask you a question in person in email?